# Cannot convert from 'const shared_ptr<base_class>' to 'shared_ptr<derived_class>'

Tags: c++, class, c++11, smart-pointers, stdvector

I have declared the following `vector`:

```
vector<shared_ptr<base_class> inventory;
```

I have the following variable:

```
shared_ptr<derived_class> equipped_item;
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
equipped_item = inventory[0];
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert from 'const shared_ptr<base_class>' to 'shared_ptr<derived_class>'
```

My question is why would I not be allowed to try to set the `equipped_item` to the selected item in the `vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert `base` class to a `derived`([down-cast](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php)), which is not implicitly convertible. In order to do that you need either `std::static_pointer_cast` (if you are sure about to what you are casting) or `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`(if the class is polymorphic) as you have used [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

For instance following is an example code for `std::static_pointer_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class base_class    {};
class derived_class: public base_class {};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<derived_class>  some_derived_ptr = std::make_shared<derived_class>();

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<base_class>> inventory{some_derived_ptr};

    std::shared_ptr<derived_class>
                equipped_item = std::static_pointer_cast<derived_class>(inventory[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `base_class` is not implicitly convertible to `derived_class` regular constructor won't work. You should use either `static_pointer_cast` (if class is not polymorphic) or `dynamic_poiner_cast` (if class is polymorphic):

```
::std::vector<::std::shared_ptr<base_class>> pointers{::std::make_shared<derived_class>()};
::std::shared_ptr<derived_class> pd{::std::static_pointer_cast<derived_class>(pointers[0])};
```

Note that need to cast from base class to derived is often a sign of incorrect class hierarchy or incorrect use of interface.

Comment: @PaulSanders Because `shared_ptr` constructors accept const-qualified lvalue references to `shared_ptr` (that is act like a copy constructors). Constructors from other set of overloads accepting a not-const-qualified rvalue references to `shared_ptr` (move like constructors) are not considered here because `pointers[0]` yields an lvalue.

Comment: OK, thanks. gcc spells it out, see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jd6nD2EIOrrwUnjC).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do the following:

```
pointer_derived =  pointer_base; //No implicit conversion possible.
```

However the following is possible:

```
pointer_base = pointer_derived; // Possible.
```

Try to explicitly downcast your pointer_base.

```
pointer_derived =  static_pointer_cast<Derived>(pointer_base);
//Since you know that pointer_base is pointing to a derived class here.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), the `shared_ptr` conversion constructor from `Y` to `T` "doesn't participate in overload resolution if `Y*` is not implicitly convertible to `T*`". You're performing a cast from base to derived which requires a `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`, it is not implicit.

You should use a [pointer cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), either `static_pointer_cast` or `dynamic_pointer_cast` depending on your class definitions.